# only got 56mb left on 8gb card after RetroPie install

Tags: sd-card, retropie

I have a formatted 8gb sd card (7.1gb available) and I've tried multiple times to install the roughly 4gb in size RetroPie disk image.

Each time I do, it says I have 55.9mb left and says it becomes FAT format when I previously formatted it to NTFS.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Did you re-size the OS partition after the install? many images are intentionally small such that they can fit on say a 4gb sd card, but then have a configuration to quickly re-size themselves to whichever size they were installed on. Also, linux tends to use multiple partitions, but the basic windows will only display the first partition.

Comment: Hmm could be the case, I'll have a look when I get home from work. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The 55mb looks like a boot partition the main part of the disk will be on the other partition, depending on distro and install method.

Comment: @rob yea I'll have to look into that. It's weird because not long ago I set up my brother Pi and I'm sure I used the exact same disk image and installed it all the same and never came across the problem..

Comment: @rob would the partitioning be something I need to do before the install or can I fix it now I've wrote the RetroPie disk image to the sd card?

Comment: It is going to be easiest to start again, as the instructions are *usually* written to build the partitions automatically. however that is not true of all the distributions and you can repartition, but I would expect it be painful. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: @rob I will do buddy. Thanks for the advice so far.

Comment: The RetroPi image is actually a real image from a disk. Including partition table. And filesystems. Hence formatting it to NTFS prior to flashing has no effect at all since the image brings along its own filesystem. EDIT: Old question is old. Y U answer, jbutewicz?

Answer (score 14):

This is always the case when installing RetroPie from the image. You have to expand the filesystem to make all of the space available to you. Go to the command line. If in Emulation Station then press F4 to get to the command line. At the command line type:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and press Enter. This will display the configuration tool. Select option 1. Expand the Filesystem an press Enter.

That's all you have to do. The full space will be available for you to use now.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Using `raspi-config` expand didn't work for me after several tries, had to do the following:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

This seemed to work as expected.

Comment: That only makes sense if you have already resized the partition somehow.